# Is it OK for SEO to also use the page title as the meta description?

Tags: seo, meta-tags, content, title, meta-description

I am new at content writing and SEO.  I am bit confused with the meta tags. When I write the meta tags for my website, is it OK to have the title same as the description?

When I am writing about the services that we do, I thought it would be effective to place the keywords in the title.  However, I am stuck with the description. Is it OK to use it again but in bullet points?

Comment: I'm not sure how bullet points could be implemented in a meta description.  It is one line of text. It doesn't have new lines or HTML formatting that would allow lists.

Answer (score 2):

The page title represents the subject of the content of each separate web page. The meta description provides a short and meaningful description of the content of each separate web page.

Check out the following **[Google guidelines for metadata](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624)**:

> Page titles should be descriptive and concise. Avoid vague descriptors
> like "Home" for your home page, or "Profile" for a specific person's
> profile.
>
> Avoid keyword stuffing.
>
> Avoid repeated or boilerplate titles. It’s important to have distinct,
> descriptive titles for each page on your site.
>
> **Why the search result title might differ from the page's  tag**
>
> If we’ve detected that a particular result has one of the above issues
> with its title, we may try to generate an improved title from anchors,
> on-page text, or other sources.
>
> Create good meta descriptions Google will sometimes use the 
> description tag from a page to generate a search results snippet, if
> we think it gives users a more accurate description than would be
> possible purely from the on-page content. A meta description tag
> should generally inform and interest users with a short, relevant
> summary of what a particular page is about. They are like a pitch that
> convince the user that the page is exactly what they're looking for.
>
> Include clearly tagged facts in the description. The meta description
> doesn't just have to be in sentence format; it's also a great place to
> include information about the page.
>
> **Use quality descriptions. Finally, make sure your descriptions are**
>
> truly descriptive. Because the meta descriptions aren't displayed in
> the pages the user sees, it's easy to let this content slide. But
> high-quality descriptions can be displayed in Google's search results,
> and can go a long way to improving the quality and quantity of your
> search traffic.

I recommend that you do not use duplicate content anywhere on your website, including metadata.

Answer (score 2):

If you struggle with creating a description try using a sentence from the page content. Or put a couple together and edit it down to a short summary. Rmr, you want it to be compelling enough that somebody will click it and go to your site. Put yourself in your user's place and think about what would make *you* click on a result. Also, rmr that feeling when a result has exactly the text you are looking for, and when you click through to the site the text isn't *anywhere* on the page, don't do that to your users. [Screaming Frog SEO Spider](https://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/) is a program that you can use for free and it will track any duplicates on your site, titles, H1s, descriptions, and content as well. It is an invaluable tool and can save you from so many mistakes.

Comment: I very often use a snippet from the page content as the meta description. It is always a safe bet.